# WPF C# - adding controls dynamically to XAML from custom class

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to write some calendar program. I need buttons in a number of days in a chosen month. I have container called "calendarPanel" and used this method to add the buttons

```
public void CreateCalendar(DateTime dt)
    {
        int numberOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.Button btn = new Button();

            calendarPanel.Children.Add(btn);
        }
    }
```

It works only added to MainWindow.xaml.cs, but I want to use that method from an instance of my class CalendarManager.cs. My problem is that I don't know how (is it possible anyway?) to reference to my panel in MainWindow from outer class (but still in the same namespace). I cannot use

```
calendarPanel.Children.Add(btn);
```

Because it doesn't see/know about "calendarPanel" element.

Comment: This is a very bad way to do WPF programming. You're making things very difficult for yourself by fighting the framework instead of working with it. I suggest you bind an ObservableCollection to an ItemsControl with an ItemsPanelTemplate containing a UniformGrid with 7 columns. Give the ItemsControl an ItemTemplate. You can google all that stuff and find many examples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: But if you don't want to learn that stuff, you can at least make `calendarPanel` a *parameter* to the `CreateCalendar` method.